# Get a set of all members with any descendant that has a member property in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to filter members across levels in a hierarchy depending on a member property that is only set at leaf level.

I have a member property set at a lower level and I am trying to filter higher level members by it. Is it possible to get a set of members that have any descendant with the property?
The purpose is to filter visible members in the hierarchy, to do that I need a measure that returns 1 for each member with the property Synlig = 1 otherwise null. The problem is that parents to visible members should also get 1 in the measure or they will be hidden.

```
create member currentcube.[Measures].[Filter] as
iif(count(
   filter([Konto].[Konto]
    ,[Konto].[Konto].Properties( "Synlig" ) = '1'
    )
) > 0, 1, null)
```

This give all the leaves with the property Synlig = 1. Leaf level is the 4th level in the hierarchy on which the property Synlig exist.
I would like to show also all headings of any members set to visible, so i need all there ancestors as well. Or 1 for the measure on all members with any descendant that has Synlig = 1

The only solution I have is to duplicate the property in 3 calculated columns, one for each level in the hierarchy 
and do:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Filter]
 AS 
CASE WHEN 
  [Konto].[Konto].CurrentMember.LEVEL.NAME = 'Level 4' AND [Konto].[Konto].CurrentMember.Properties( "Synlig" ) = '1' 
  THEN 1 
WHEN 
  [Konto].[Konto].CurrentMember.LEVEL.NAME = 'Level 3' AND [Konto].[Konto].Properties( "Synlig L3" ) = '1'
  THEN 1 
WHEN [Konto].[Konto].CurrentMember.LEVEL.NAME = 'Level 2' AND [Konto].[Konto].Properties( "Synlig L2" ) = '1'
  THEN 1
WHEN [Konto].[Konto].CurrentMember.LEVEL.NAME = 'Level 1' AND [Konto].[Konto].Properties( "Synlig L1" ) = '1'
  THEN 1 
     ELSE NULL
END
```

Answer (score 2):

I will just give you the solution based on Adventure Works cube since I do not have your cube to try, but the principle will be the same:

So, basically you want to flag any member in the hierarchy that has a descendant on the leaf level that has certain property set to certain value (in your case Synlig property set to 1).

In Adventure Works I will create MyFilter measure that will flag any member of Date.Calendar hierarchy as 1 if that member has a descendant on the leaf level that has Name property set to  'January 1, 2005'. The code will look like this:

```
with member Measures.MyFilter as count(FILTER( Descendants([Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER, ,leaves) 
,[Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("Name") =  'January 1, 2005' ))

  select MyFilter on 0,
 [Date].[Calendar].members on 1
  from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

So you will take all leaves of your hierarchy with `Descendants([Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER, ,leaves)` , then you will filter this set of leaves with this condition `[Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("Name") =  'January 1, 2005'` and at the end you will just count number of members left in the set. So `'January 1, 2005'` and all it's parents up the hierarchy, will have MyFilter set to 1 as you can see in the picture.

If you want a result set to consists only of members with MyFilter value set to 1, you will just have to add filter like this:

```
with member Measures.MyFilter as count(FILTER( Descendants([Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER, ,leaves) 
,[Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("Name") =  'January 1, 2005' ))

  select MyFilter on 0,
  FILTER([Date].[Calendar].members, Measures.MyFilter>0) on 1
  from [Adventure Works]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by instead adding the "Synlig" column not as a property, but created a measure form it with a fact relation (dimension and measure in same table).

Actually a calculated column with Synlig as an int instead of a bit. Then it will aggregate up and all members I wanted to have 0 in the example above will be 0 and all members with at least one Synlig = 1 below them will be greater then 0.